# Is there any relationship between memory access time and clock speed of processor?

Tags: cpu, clock

I was just studying my computer organization topic and came across words and the time taken to access words, memory access time. So this has something to do with the processor. Then I thought of the clock speed, how many instructions it executes or reads. And I just want to know whether there is any relationship between the two or I just need to understand both deeper.

Comment: Typically L1 caches are tightly synchronized to the processor core such that access time on a hit is a fixed number of clock cycles, but the farther removed the component of the memory hierarchy is from the core the less tightly it tends to be synchronized with the core. Crossing clock rate boundaries generally adds latency and so is more expensive for low latency close levels of cache. Moving off-chip is an especially good boundary for having a clock boundary and DRAM latency traits are sufficiently different to justify a less tightly synchronized interface. Etc.